# How to stop from deleting a file/workbook in MS excel when it is already open?

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

We have designed Microsoft Addins for MS Excel and Word 2019 written in VB.net.
There we have designed a tab, on clicking this tab, we open a Task Pane.
On loading this task pane, we execute a code to launch another Excel File/Word file.

So when I delete a file in MS Word that is already open it shows an exception The file 'Filename' already exists.
Given below is the code snippet I am using to delete an already existing open file named processFile

*My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(processFile)*

Now when I run the same code snippet in MS Excel it does not show this exception and deletes the file.

I am not able to understand this behavior.
Kindly suggest if anyone has understanding on it

Here is some more information about which environment I'm working in:

**Operating System** : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

**Code Editor** : Visual Studio 2019

**Technology** : Vb.net(.Net Framework 4.8)

**MS Office Version** : 2019(32 bit) : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0):

The [IOException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ioexception?view=net-6.0) should be thrown if the file is in use. You need to close any editors first and then delete files.

Comment: Yes exactly, IOException shows in MS Word when i delete already open file but does not come in MS Excel. 
That's what my issue is

Comment: Is it possible that a copy of the file was opened in MS Excel?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, it looks that program is working fine on word and not working on excel. Even user is saying that file has deleted but it is kept open in excel editor. Can it be a Microsoft Excel issue or do you have any alternative.

Comment: Is the file opened under the protected mode? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev 
Yes, when I open the file in protected mode I do not get any exception and the file gets deleted but when the file is open in Edit mode it shows an IOException and it does not delete the file

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is open. I have a code below that may help.

As import sfile use the fullpath with filename. (eg. "C:\Windows\test.txt")
returns True when file it's open and false when it isn't.

Yu will need "Imports System.IO"

```
 Public Function IsFileInUse(sFile As String) As Boolean
        Try
            If File.Exists(sFile) Then
                Using f As New IO.FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
                End Using
            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Return True
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function
```

Comment: Hi
I just checked the snippet you have provided above.
It is returning "False", even file is showing in open mode and deleted from the drive.

Answer (score 0):

*As per the information in the comment section, the file is opened in "protected mode" and you are saying that it is deleting while it is still open to the user.*

So yes, if the file is engaged and deleted by some program, it should throw an exception and not delete. But if no exception is coming, i.e. some specific handling has been done by Windows/MS Excel so that file has been deleted while it is still kept on buffer and open. Its answer can be given by Microsoft only.

**One solution**, I can suggest is to close the "protected object" and then delete the file so that no file will be opened to the user and it will be safely deleted.

**Snippet to open the file for Add-ins(VSTO):**

`Dim objProtectedMode As String objProtectedMode = Globals.Connect.Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Open(fileLocation, , False, False)`

**Snippet to delete the file safely:**

```
If Not (objProtectedMode Is Nothing) Then
objProtectedMode.Close()
End If

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(objProtectedMode)
```

*Note: - Solution may vary for other add-ins. Code snippet provided for VSTO Add-ins.*